# SQL Query runs very slow once expanded to full data? Subquery is culprit

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below works great (a couple of seconds) if I define one Computer Name in where, however once I remove the specific computer name from the where, it takes more than 5 minutes (I didn't proceed long enough for results).

```
select distinct
v_GS_PC_BIOS.SerialNumber0 AS SerialNumber,
v_R_System.Name0 AS Hostname,
v_R_System.Distinguished_Name0 AS ADContainer,
v_R_System.User_Name0 AS LastUser,
v_R_System.Affinity_Full_Name0 AS AffinityUser,
v_R_User.Mail0 AS EmailLU,
v_R_User.telephonenumber AS PhoneLU,
v_CollectionMemberClientBaselineStatus.LastActiveTime AS LastCommunication,
v_R_System.ResourceID,

CASE v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ChassisTypes0
when 8 THEN 'Laptop'
when 9 THEN 'Laptop'
when 10 THEN 'Laptop'
when 14 THEN 'Laptop'
when 15 THEN 'Desktop'
when 21 THEN 'Laptop'
When 3 THEN 'Desktop'
When 4 THEN 'Desktop'
When 6 THEN 'Desktop'
When 7 THEN 'Desktop'
When 13 THEN 'Desktop'
When 12 THEN 'Docking Station'
when 16 THEN 'Lunchbox'
When 32 THEN 'Tablet_Conv'
END as "Chassis Type",
v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Model0 AS "Model"

from v_GS_PC_BIOS

left JOIN v_R_System ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_GS_PC_BIOS.ResourceID
left JOIN v_r_user ON v_r_user.User_Name0 = v_R_System.User_Name0
left JOIN v_GS_NETWORK_LOGIN_PROFILE ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_GS_NETWORK_LOGIN_PROFILE.ResourceID
left JOIN v_CollectionMemberClientBaselineStatus ON v_GS_NETWORK_LOGIN_PROFILE.ResourceID = v_CollectionMemberClientBaselineStatus.MachineID
left join v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE on v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ResourceID = v_GS_PC_BIOS.ResourceID
left join v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM on v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID = v_GS_PC_BIOS.ResourceID
Join (select v_GS_PC_BIOS.SerialNumber0, max(v_CollectionMemberClientBaselineStatus.LastActiveTime) as recent_datetime 
            from v_GS_PC_BIOS
                left JOIN v_R_System ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_GS_PC_BIOS.ResourceID
                left JOIN v_CollectionMemberClientBaselineStatus ON v_GS_PC_BIOS.ResourceID = v_CollectionMemberClientBaselineStatus.MachineID
            Group by v_GS_PC_BIOS.SerialNumber0) T1  on v_GS_PC_BIOS.SerialNumber0 = T1.SerialNumber0

where v_GS_PC_BIOS.SerialNumber0 IS NOT NULL and
v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE.ChassisTypes0 not like '12' and 
v_CollectionMemberClientBaselineStatus.LastActiveTime  = T1.recent_datetime and
v_R_System.Name0 = 'ComputerName'
```

If I take it a step further and comment out the subquery, it takes about 10 seconds to run.

Comment: Why would you want/need a `SELECT *`; from your `JOIN`s alone there would be repeated data. Just return the columns you need; you don't need *all* of them.

Comment: Why do you always use `LEFT JOIN`s too when you then require some columns to have a non-`NULL` value from those tables?

Comment: I am guessing by the names that those are all views? Do those views also select from other views? I would suggest you start getting comfortable with aliases in your queries. It would cut down the amount of typing significantly. It also will make these queries easier to read.

Comment: @Larnu Sorry, I didn't mean to use *, I just meant remove the individual computer from the where statement.

Comment: @Larnu. Non-NULL is for testing only

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, all of these query views. I denfinatly agree with alias', however I dont do this every day and i need to be able to read it without referencing.

Comment: The first thing to look at is your use of `DISTINCT`. Using DISTINCT to eliminate duplicates without knowing where those duplicates are coming from may be hiding under-constrained joins or parallel independent joins that in turn may be causing an explosion of your data.  Even 10 the seconds to process one computer name seems hugely excessive.  With the proper structure and indexes in place, you should expect perhaps single digit milliseconds.  Comment out the DISTINCT and debug your query from that point to see if you can figure out where the excessive workload is coming from.

Comment: *"Non-NULL is for testing only"* do your clauses like `v_R_System.Name0 = 'ComputerName'` are actually in the `ON` not the `WHERE`, @My9to5 ? Then [edit] your question to demonstrate that, don't provide a sample with `LEFT JOIN`s that are implicit `INNER JOIN`s.

Comment: If you replace the select list with `select count(*)`, how many records do you get with the `ComputerName` condition in place. How many without that condition? If your counts are way in excess of what you reasonably expect in the final result, start commenting out the joins to identify the cause(s).

Comment: What is a "Buna, DIn Nou", @BogdanSahlean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Not necessarily a complete answer, but a perhaps a step forward and way too much to fit in a comment.)

Looking at the subselect, I see that it duplicates already-joined tables `v_GS_PC_BIOS`, `v_R_System`, and `v_CollectionMemberClientBaselineStatus` with the apparent intention of actually filtering the `v_CollectionMemberClientBaselineStatus` for the latest `LastActiveTime` per `SerialNumber0`.

It is unclear to me whether or not `SerialNumber0` uniquely identifies a `v_GS_PC_BIOS` row or if the joined `v_R_System` and/or `v_CollectionMemberClientBaselineStatus` rows of the main query might be different from those active in the subquery. Assuming that they are the same, the latest `v_CollectionMemberClientBaselineStatus` might best be selected using an `OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ...)`.

The updated query below demonstrates this. I took the liberty of applying table aliases throughout and making the `ON` conditions consistently read as `this.column = other.column` (many prefer the reverse). I also removed what appeared to be a redundant constraint of: profile ResourceID equal to both system ResourceID and baseline BL.MachineID.

The result is:

```
select distinct
    B.SerialNumber0 AS SerialNumber,
    S.Name0 AS Hostname,
    S.Distinguished_Name0 AS ADContainer,
    S.User_Name0 AS LastUser,
    S.Affinity_Full_Name0 AS AffinityUser,
    U.Mail0 AS EmailLU,
    U.telephonenumber AS PhoneLU,
    BL.LastActiveTime AS LastCommunication,
    S.ResourceID,
    CASE E.ChassisTypes0
        when 8 THEN 'Laptop'
        when 9 THEN 'Laptop'
        when 10 THEN 'Laptop'
        when 14 THEN 'Laptop'
        when 15 THEN 'Desktop'
        when 21 THEN 'Laptop'
        When 3 THEN 'Desktop'
        When 4 THEN 'Desktop'
        When 6 THEN 'Desktop'
        When 7 THEN 'Desktop'
        When 13 THEN 'Desktop'
        When 12 THEN 'Docking Station'
        when 16 THEN 'Lunchbox'
        When 32 THEN 'Tablet_Conv'
        END as "Chassis Type",
    C.Model0 AS "Model"

from v_GS_PC_BIOS B
left join v_R_System S on S.ResourceID = B.ResourceID
left join v_r_user U on U.User_Name0 = S.User_Name0
left join v_GS_NETWORK_LOGIN_PROFILE P on P.ResourceID = S.ResourceID
outer apply (
    select top 1 *
    from v_CollectionMemberClientBaselineStatus BL
    where BL.MachineID = B.ResourceID
    order by BL.LastActiveTime desc
) BL
left join v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE E on E.ResourceID = B.ResourceID
left join v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM C on C.ResourceID = B.ResourceID

where B.SerialNumber0 IS NOT NULL
and E.ChassisTypes0 not like '12'
and S.Name0 = 'ComputerName'
```

The contents of the outer apply could also be moved to a Common Table Expression, which could potentially be more efficient in some scenarios by preselecting all of the latest baselines in one pass through the view.

```
;with LatestBaselines AS (
    select *
    from (
        select
            *,
            row_number() over(partition by MachineID
                              order by LastActiveTime desc) AS RowNum
        from v_CollectionMemberClientBaselineStatus
    ) A
    where A.RowNum = 1
)
select distinct
    B.SerialNumber0 AS SerialNumber,
    S.Name0 AS Hostname,
    S.Distinguished_Name0 AS ADContainer,
    S.User_Name0 AS LastUser,
    S.Affinity_Full_Name0 AS AffinityUser,
    U.Mail0 AS EmailLU,
    U.telephonenumber AS PhoneLU,
    BL.LastActiveTime AS LastCommunication,
    S.ResourceID,
    CASE E.ChassisTypes0
        when 8 THEN 'Laptop'
        when 9 THEN 'Laptop'
        when 10 THEN 'Laptop'
        when 14 THEN 'Laptop'
        when 15 THEN 'Desktop'
        when 21 THEN 'Laptop'
        When 3 THEN 'Desktop'
        When 4 THEN 'Desktop'
        When 6 THEN 'Desktop'
        When 7 THEN 'Desktop'
        When 13 THEN 'Desktop'
        When 12 THEN 'Docking Station'
        when 16 THEN 'Lunchbox'
        When 32 THEN 'Tablet_Conv'
        END as "Chassis Type",
    C.Model0 AS "Model"

from v_GS_PC_BIOS B
left join v_R_System S on S.ResourceID = B.ResourceID
left join v_r_user U on U.User_Name0 = S.User_Name0
left join v_GS_NETWORK_LOGIN_PROFILE P on P.ResourceID = S.ResourceID
left join LatestBaselines BL on BL.MachineID = B.ResourceID
left join v_GS_SYSTEM_ENCLOSURE E on E.ResourceID = B.ResourceID
left join v_GS_COMPUTER_SYSTEM C on C.ResourceID = B.ResourceID

where B.SerialNumber0 IS NOT NULL
and E.ChassisTypes0 not like '12'
and S.Name0 = 'ComputerName'
```

I don't guarantee that there might be subtle changes in the resulting join behavior, so double check the results.

This might or might not improve the performance issues. If not or if the improvement is not significant, the next step is for you to capture and post the entire execution plan along with supporting schema (tables, views, indexes, foreign key constraints, etc.)

Comment: Initially I thought you nailed it...certainly did in the efficiency part! There is one issue I noticed when spot checking is that if I define ```serialnumber0 = 'Serial'``` in the where, there are duplicates in the results. I think because if the ```BL.LastActiveTime``` is ```NULL``` it will order that on top. I did try to add ```and B.ResourceID IS NOT NULL``` to both the sub and outer queries separately, but the ```NULL``` row is still present

Comment: The `order by BL.LastActiveTime desc` should put any null values at the end of the list, so I don't think that would be happening. Would there be any v_GS_PC_BIOS records with the same ResourceID but different  SerialNumber0 values or vice versa? Do any of your views yield multiple records with the same ResourceID? Check `SELECT COUNT(*) AS N, ResourceID FROM v_XYZ GROUP BY ResourceID HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2` for each view. Ultimately, you should strive to eliminate the need for DISTINCT. With a very limited view of what you are doing and no visibility of the data, I can only speculate.

Comment: I just ```where ResourceID IS NOT NULL``` and I think that will do it because that field cannot be null.  5 second run time! This changes most of our reports because they are all the same format. Thanks so much!